# How to remove duplicate entries from associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

My array is

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [new_id] => 958
                [affiliate_id] => 33
           )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [new_id] => 959
                [affiliate_id] => 45
           )
         [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [new_id] => 960
                [affiliate_id] => 23
           )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23
                [new_id] => 961
                [affiliate_id] => 33
           )
    )
```

and i want array

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [new_id] => 958
                [affiliate_id] => 33
           )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [new_id] => 959
                [affiliate_id] => 45
           )
         [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [new_id] => 960
                [affiliate_id] => 23
           )
      )
```

I want to remove duplicates value of `affiliate_id` . According to first array i am getting `affiliate_id`'s value is `33` for two time. But i want it for one time. So in my second array (which will be my answer) i remove it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i am trying this thing $unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $affiliate))); Here $affiliate is my array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, not so pretty as `array_` one liners, but still:

```
$existing_aff_ids = array();
$unique = array();
foreach ($affiliate as $aff) {
    if (!isset($existing_aff_ids[$aff['affiliate_id']])) {
        $unique[] = $aff;
        $existing_aff_ids[$aff['affiliate_id']] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not duplicate values :

```
 1. $input = array_map("unserialize",
    array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data))

 2. array_values(array_unique($data))
```

Both this case fails because of the unique id values are there it requires all values to be same to consider it as duplicate.

Solution:Will making the array check the value of the corresponding field.

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
    {
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $val2 = arrayUnique($val);
        }
        else
        {
            $val2 = $val;
            $newArray=array_unique($data);
            $newArray=deleteEmpty($newArray);
            break;
        }
        if (!empty($val2))
        {
            $newArray[$key] = $val2;
        }
    }
```

print_r($newArray);

Answer (score 0):

Given `$affiliates` as in your answer, looping over the array and checking for `affiliate_id` would do the trick

```
$unique_affiliates = array();
foreach($affiliates as $affiliate) {
    $affiliate_key = $affiliate['key'];

    /* Variant 1 */
    $unique_affiliates[$affiliate_key] = $affiliate;

    /* Variant 2 */
    if(!isset($unique_affiliates[$affiliate_key])) {
         $unique_affiliates[$affiliate_key] = $affiliate;
    }
}
```

All entries in `$unique_affiliates` will have unique `affiliate_key`s. Variant 1 will contain the last occurrence of each `afffiliate_key` (as in your example), whereas variant 2 will add the first occurrence of any `affiliate_key` and just ignore all subsequent ones.

Comment: Good. To get back to zero-indexed array `array_values()` can be used.